# Run multiple recursive Promises and break when requested

Tags: javascript, recursion, bluebird

I'm working on a LED strip animation tool which allows the user to select multiple effects which can run simultaneously. Each effect is a (bluebird) Promise. There is a single `run()` method which sets the color of the LED strip.

All promises run at a fixed FPS using the `delay` method.

```
run(mode) {
    return this.setStripColor(this.color).delay(1 / this.fps).then(() => { this.run(1 / this.fps) })
}

// example of an effect
rainbowSweep() {
    // .. 
    // magical unicorn code
    // ..
    return Promise.resolve().delay(1 / this.fps).then(() => {
        this.rainbowSweep()
    })

app.rainbowSweep()
app.run()
```

Is there some sort of data structure that I can use where I can toggle on and off a recursive promise? In other words, how do I signal to the effect (the recursive promise) to stop recursing?

I was thinking of an array containing all the promises. 
But then I don't know how to break/resolve a recursive promise when it's no longer in the array. I could do a check before I `return` whether the promise itself is inside the array, but I was hoping there was a more elegant way.

Comment: A promise is simply a notification mechanism for an underlying asynchronous operation.  You don't toggle a promise.  If you want to stop the underlying asynchronous operation, then you communicate with it directly and let it notify completion through the promise (resolve or reject).  The promise is NOT the actual asynchronous operation.  It's just a notification mechanism.  So, if you want to stop the asynchronous operation, then you need to communicate directly with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at a simple recursive function that expresses our program at a high level

```
let RUNNING =
  true

const main = async (elem, color = Color ()) =>
  RUNNING
    ? delay (color, FPS)
        .then (effect (color => setElemColor (elem, color)))
        .then (color => main (elem, stepColor (color)))
    : color
```

We've done a little wishful thinking with `Color`, `stepColor`, and `setElemColor` (among others), let's implement those first

```
const Color = (r = 128, g = 128, b = 128) =>
  ({ r, g, b })

const stepColor = ({ r, g, b }, step = 8) =>
  b < 255
    ? Color (r, g, b + step)
    : g < 255
      ? Color (r, g + step, 0)
      : r < 255
        ? Color (r + step, 0, 0)
        : Color (0, 0, 0)

const setElemColor = (elem, { r, g, b }) =>
  elem.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`

const c = new Color () // { r: 128, g: 128, b: 128 }
setpColor (c)          // { r: 128, g: 128, b: 136 }
```

Now we have a way to create colors, get the "next" color, and we can set the color of an HTML element

Lastly, we write helpers `delay` and `effect`. `delay` will create a Promised value that resolves in `ms` milliseconds. `effect` is used for functions which have a side effect (like setting the property of an HTML element). and `FPS` is just our frames-per-second constant

```
const delay = (x, ms) =>
  new Promise (r => setTimeout (r, ms, x))

const effect = f => x =>
  (f (x), x)

const FPS =
  1000 / 30
```

To run the program, just call `main` with an input element. Because it's an asynchronous program, don't forget to handle both the success *and* errors cases. When the program finally stops, the last used color will be output.

```
main (document.querySelector('#main'))
  .then (console.log, console.error)
  // => { Color r: 136, g: 8, b: 40 }
```

To stop the program, just set `RUNNING = false` at any time

```
// stop after 5 seconds
setTimeout (() => RUNNING = false, 5000)
```

Here's a working demo

```js
const Color = (r = 128, g = 128, b = 128) =>
  ({ r, g, b })

const stepColor = ({ r, g, b }, step = 16) =>
  b < 255
    ? Color (r, g, b + step)
    : g < 255
      ? Color (r, g + step, 0)
      : r < 255
        ? Color (r + step, 0, 0)
        : Color (0, 0, 0)

const setElemColor = (elem, { r, g, b }) =>
  elem.style.backgroundColor = `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, 1)`

const delay = (x, ms) =>
  new Promise (r => setTimeout (r, ms, x))

const effect = f => x =>
  (f (x), x)

const FPS =
  1000 / 60
 
let RUNNING =
  true
  
const main = async (elem, color = Color ()) =>
  RUNNING
    ? delay (color, FPS)
        .then (effect (color => setElemColor (elem, color)))
        .then (color => main (elem, stepColor (color)))
    : color

main (document.querySelector('#main'))
  .then (console.log, console.error)
  // => { r: 136, g: 8, b: 40 }
  
// stop after 5 seconds
setTimeout (() => RUNNING = false, 5000)
```

```css
#main {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
<p>runs for 5 seconds...</p>
```

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?

Comment: @jfriend00 run promises recursively and break when requested?

Comment: Is that what you think the OP is asking?   This is an awful lot of code to communicate that.  FYI, you don't "run" promises.  You run asynchronous operations - promises provide notification about asynchronous operations.

Comment: The OP describes an animated LED; I provided a mvce in under 50 lines. If you think `main` is an “awful lot”, I can’t wait to see your comment on guest271314’s answer

Comment: FYI I don’t see where I said you “run” Promises

Comment: Right in the comment I was responding to.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of using an async generator where the iteration can be stopped using `return` or `break`

```js
const o = {
  value: new Map,
  done: false,
  async * gen(...props) {
    while (!this.done) {
      if (this.value.size && !this.done) {
        try {
          for (const [key, val] of this.value) {
            // yield* [{key, value: await Promise.all([].concat(val).map(prop => typeof prop === "function" ? prop() : prop)).then(values => { this.value.delete(key); return values }).catch(err => {console.log(err); return {error:[key, err]}})}];    
            // does not interrupt immediately when `this.done` is set to `true`

            for await (const value of [].concat(val).map(prop => Promise.resolve(typeof prop === "function" ? prop() : prop).then(prop => {console.log("prop:", prop); return prop}, err => {
              console.error("caught at for await:", err); return err;
            }))) {
              console.log("value:", value);
              if (key !== undefined && value !== undefined && !o.done)
                yield * [{
                  key, value
                }];
            }
            this.value.delete(key);

          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("caught at async:", error);
          throw error
        }
      } else {
        // yield await `no value at ${new Date()}`;
        this.done = true;
        break;
      }
    }

  }
};

(async() => {

  let n = 0;
  let caught, gen;

  try {
    gen = o.gen();
    next = new Proxy(o.value.set.bind(o.value), {
      apply(target, _, args) {
        // console.log(args);
        if (!o.done && args.length) {
          Reflect.apply(target, null, args);
          return gen.next().catch(err => {
            throw err
          })
        };
        if (!args.length && !o.done) return gen.next().catch(err => Promise.reject(err));
        if (o.done) {
          caught = "we're done here";
          return gen.throw(caught).catch(err => {throw err})
        };

      }
    });

    await next(n, Promise.resolve(0)).catch(err => {
        throw err
      })
      .then(({
        value, done
      }) => console.log(value, done));

    await next(++n, Promise.resolve(1))
      .catch(err => {
        throw err
      })
      .then(({
        value, done
      }) => console.log(value, done));

    await next(++n, [Promise.resolve(2)])
      .catch(err => {
        throw err
      })
      .then(({
        value, done
      }) => console.log(value, done));   

    await next(++n, [() => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000, 3))
                    , () => new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(_, 6000, 4))
                    , () => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 4000, 5))
                    ]
      )
      .catch(err => {
        throw err
      })
      .then(({
        value, done
      }) => console.log(value, done));

    // o.done = true; // stop generator
   while (o.value.size && !o.value.done) {
      await next()
        .catch(err => {
          throw err
        }).then(({
          value, done
        }) => {
          console.log(value, done, o.value.size);
          return
        })
   }

  } catch (e) {
    let message = await e;
    if (message === "we're done here") {
      console.error("err:", message);
    } else {
      console.error("caught at catch:", message);
      throw new Error(message)
    }
  } finally {
    console.log(gen);
    if (caught) throw new Error(caught)
    return {done: o.done, value: o.value.size}
  }

})()
.catch(err => { console.error("ok caught:", err); return err})
.then(done => console.log("done:", done));

async function* gen(n) {
  let i = 1;
  while(true) {
    let curr = yield await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000, i));
    if (curr) {
      i *= curr;
    };
    i *= 25;
    if (i > 500 * 500) break;
  }
}

async function read(n) {
  const g = gen(n);
  // while ( await g.next().then(({value, done}) => {console.log(value, done); return !done}) );
  await g.next().then(({value, done}) => {console.log(value, done); return !done});
  await g.next(100).then(({value, done}) => {console.log(value, done); return !done});
  await g.next().then(({value, done}) => {console.log(value, done); return !done});
  await g.next().then(({value, done}) => {console.log(value, done); return !done});
}

read(5)
```

Comment: Note that there are several ways to stop the generator: set `o.done` to `true`, `return` or `throw` from the `Proxy` which observes `getter` of `Map` instance or `break` the generator

Answer (score 0):

I might be way off base with my interpretation of your question, but I think you're trying to resolve the initial promise after all the recursion is done. If that's what you're asking, you can pass the initial promise thru to each recursive call.

I'd use your example code in my example but you're missing the closing brace on your function so I'm not really sure what it's supposed to look like.. here's a general example of the concept..

```js
var recusion_counter = 0;

function myRecusivePromiseFunction(prm){
  return new Promise(done=>{
    recusion_counter++;
    prm = prm || done;
    if(recusion_counter >= 5) prm();
    else myRecusivePromiseFunction(prm);
  });
}

myRecusivePromiseFunction().then(()=>{
  console.log(recusion_counter);
});
```